# Asymptotic Distribution of the Likelihoodfunction

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid. Poisson distributed random variables with density $$f_\theta(x)=e^{-\theta}\frac{\theta^x}{x!},\ x\in\mathbb{N}$$

I computed the Likelihoodfunction for $\theta$:$$f(\underline{x},\theta)=e^{-n\theta}\frac{\theta^{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}}{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i!}$$

Now i want to determine how $f(\underline{x},\theta)$ behaves asymptotically, but I cannot seem to make any progress. My attempts mainly revolved around this

> *Theorem:* Let $\theta_0$ be the true value of the parameter $\theta$. Under certain regularity conditions (we will take them for granted) the log likelihood estimate $\hat\theta_n$ satisfies $$I_n(\theta)^{1/2}(\hat\theta_n - \theta_0)\rightarrow Z$$ where $Z$ has a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ distribution and *convergence is in distribution*.

I suspect there are simpler methods to do this.

Comment: The pmf and likelihood have typos. And the theorem you state says in this case that $\hat\theta_n=\sum X_i/n$ is asymptotically normal. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I corrected the typos. I am actually looking for $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(\underline{x},\theta)$ I just wanted to show my approach.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Isn't this limit zero? You multiply the probabilities, the largest of which is strongly less than $1$.

Comment: What are $I_n(\theta)$ and $\theta_0$ here?